# WatchOS Notifications Firing Late

Tags: swiftui, notifications, watchos, unusernotificationcenter

We have a watchos app that uses notifications to display time sensitive information to the users. We are using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false), our usernotification center looks like this

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("It got here to showing the notifications and this is when it is shown: \(Date()) and this is the type of notification: \(notification.request.identifier)")
        completionHandler([ .list, .sound, .banner ])
        
    }.
```

The problem is that the usernotification center is called correctly but no notification is given, every time 13 seconds later it is called twice again and only then does the notification display to the users.

I have tried changing the type of trigger for the notification but even that did not get rid of the thirteen second delay.

Comment: This has been happening for years and there are a couple of posts on the Apple developer forums about it. The delay only happens if the iOS companion app is installed. Deleting the iPhone app removes the delay for notifications scheduled on the Watch. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696280